# How to enable debug of dhcp client on Windows 7

Tags: windows, dhcp, debugging

Is it possible to enable some sort of debugging for dhcp client on Windows 7?

Answer (score 10):

> Go to Event Viewer, Applications and Services Logs, Microsoft, Windows, Dhcp-Client, Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Operational.
>
> By default this trace log will be empty, because you need to enable it by clicking on “Enable log” on the right side.

Source: http://texhex.blogspot.be/2011/12/debugging-dhcp-on-client.html

Answer (score 2):

Windows Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe) will capture events/error generated by the DHCP Client, here you'll be able to see when and if a address was requested (DHCPREQUEST) and what the reply from the server was (DHCPACK / DHCPNACK)
(These events are in the system part of the Eventviewer utility)

---